# SDL on STM32F4 (write in C)

Tags: stm32, lcd, nintendo, asl

Is it possible to use the SDL library (in C) on the STM32F4DISCOVERY? 
Procesor 168mhz and LCD 480x272 4'3 inch.

I want to know because i want to do a nes emulator for the STM

Answer (score 1):

You dont use sdl there. You can write directly to the display. Sdl is for desktops.